# Show dialog above view pager that has nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I have setup a very simple test project https://github.com/ArtworkAD/ViewPagerDialogTest to evaluate following situation: the main activity has a view pager which hosts a single fragment using support fragment manager:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        // ...
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        MainActivity.CustomDialog dialog = (MainActivity.CustomDialog) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainActivity.CustomDialog.TAG);

        if (dialog == null) {
            new MainActivity.CustomDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), MainActivity.CustomDialog.TAG);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

When the activity is resumed a dialog fragment is shown inside the main activity.

The single fragment inside the view pager is defined like this:

```
public class RootFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.root_fragment, container, false);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.root_frame, new FirstLevelFragment(), "ROOT").commit();
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

This root fragment allows us to stack other fragments on the "root_frame". So we stack another and another:

```
public class FirstLevelFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_level_fragment, container, false);
        root.findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SecondLevelFragment f = (SecondLevelFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("NESTED");
                if (f == null) {
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.root_frame, new SecondLevelFragment(), "NESTED").addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    public static class SecondLevelFragment extends Fragment {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setRetainInstance(true);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_level_fragment, container, false);
        }
    }
}
```

This works great! The stacking idea is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21453571/401025 . However when dialog is shown and the users goes to the second level fragment and rotates the screen I get following exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{de.azzoft.viewpagerdialogtest/de.azzoft.viewpagerdialogtest.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0083
>   (de.azzoft.viewpagerdialogtest:id/root_frame) for fragment
>   SecondLevelFragment{15c0db38 #0 id=0x7f0c0083 NESTED}
>
> E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
>   view found for id 0x7f0c0083
>   (de.azzoft.viewpagerdialogtest:id/root_frame) for fragment
>   SecondLevelFragment{15c0db38 #0 id=0x7f0c0083 NESTED}

Full stack trace: https://github.com/ArtworkAD/ViewPagerDialogTest/blob/master/README.md

Without the dialog appearing everything works great. You can test it by downloading the test project.

It seems that the dialog, which is actually a fragment, messes up fragment hierarchy when it is added to the activity. Any ideas how to fix this?

It is important that the second fragment is retained.

Comment: i am working on fixing it now

Comment: Could you try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296868/how-to-add-a-fragment-to-a-programmatically-generated-layout)

Comment: @Yvette  The "SecondLevelFragment" should be retained. Nested is maybe wrong to say, better: added on top of "FirstLevelFragment". But actually if you look at the code you will understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
No view found for id 0x7f0c0083 (de.azzoft.viewpagerdialogtest:id/root_frame) for fragment SecondLevelFragment
```

When `Activity` recreates on rotate, the `Activity FragmentManger` tries to add the `SecondLevelFragment` into `R.id.root_frame` . But the `root_frame` view is not in Activity layout, its in `FirstLevelFragment` layout. Thats why the app crashes.

You have to make two changes to fix this issue.

Add the `FirstLevelFragment` into the `RootFragment` using the `getChildFragmentManager`

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.root_frame, new FirstLevelFragment(), "ROOT").commit();
```

Add the `SecondLevelFragment` using `FragmentManager`

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.root_frame, new SecondLevelFragment(), "NESTED").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Finally remove the `setRetainInstance` from `FirstLevelFragment` and `SecondLevelFragment` as nested fragments doesn't required to set retain.

If you need to pop back the `SecondLevelFragment` on back press you need to pass the back press the event to RootFragment and pop from back stack.

Override the back press on activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager);
    if(fragment instanceof RootFragment){
        boolean handled = ((RootFragment)fragment).onBackPressed();
        if(handled){
            return;
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And handle the back press on `RootFragment`

```
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    int count = getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if(count > 0){
        getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I created a Pull request to your repository . please check 
https://github.com/ArtworkAD/ViewPagerDialogTest/pull/1

Let me know if any questions.

Comment: It fixes the exception but the second level fragment cannot be popped from the back stack any more.

Comment: Its possible to pop back the second level fragment from `RootFragment`. Please check the updated answer to handle back press.

Comment: First it looked like this is the solution but now I noticed that child fragment manager cannot retain its fragments. I think this is a bug?

Comment: Yes this is a know bug. Please check this blog http://ideaventure.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/nested-retained-fragment-lost-state.html for workaround. There is a google ticket , but no fix yet. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74222

Answer (score 1):

If you override onDismiss so resolved crash. enjoy it.

```
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        DialogFragment dialog = (DialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);

        if(dialog == null){
            CustomDialog.newInstance().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);

        }


    }


   public static class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {


        public static CustomDialog newInstance() {
            CustomDialog d = new CustomDialog();
            return d;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
//            super.onDismiss(dialog);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onDismiss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
//            super.onCancel(dialog);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setRetainInstance(true);

        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Dialog");
            builder.setMessage("This is a message!");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            return builder.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In production I currently do as you say, however the dialog fragment is superior to plain alert dialog.

Comment: this is a bug so you can not using dialogfragment. i suggested you using this https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs for dialog

Comment: why is this working? I mean I check it and the problem is solved, but why?

Comment: Or I tested it and realized that overriding onDismiss like you do will not correctly remove the dialog fragment from back stack.

Comment: Root, first & second fragment after every rotation still in backstack. I do force dialogfragment still in backstack like other fragments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **keep the state** of your `Fragments` you should use a [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html).

From the docs:

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that uses a Fragment to manage each
>   page. This class also handles saving and restoring of fragment's
>   state.

If you use this you can also remove the `setRetainInstance(true)` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had downloaded your Test app and it seems that I have fixed the problem.

In your `FirstLevelFragment` class, comment the following line

```
 //if (nestedNestedFragment == null) {
     getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.root_frame, new SecondLevelFragment(), "NESTED").addToBackStack(null).commit();
 //}
```

And

Comment `setRetainInstance(true);` in `SecondLevelFragment`

Comment: I assume the second Fragment will not be retained anymore when I do as you advise?

Comment: okay, I assumed the intention was to show dialog. no worries will look into it futher

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` of your Activity. See your Fragment can not be added without a View hierarchy. Your Fragment is hosted by an activity. So you need to set the content to the activity first.

Hope this Helps,
Thanks.